# Как создать свой имитатор клавиатуры в одной Activity?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

В некоторых приложениях реализовано что-то типа клавиатуры в виде кнопок. Мне нужно чтобы при вводе в EditText вызывалась не клавиатура Android, а использовалась моя заготовка в виде кнопок, которая будет находится внизу экрана. Вот тут наглядно видно:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При нажатии на белый прямоугольник ввод реализуется не с помощью клавиатуры Android, а кнопки внизу экрана. Как такое реализовать?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25786272/how-to-display-custom-keyboard-when-clicking-on-edittext-in-android

Comment: Назначайте каждой кнопке видимость